# Heatmap over static map

Tags: php, static, mapbox, heatmap

I am trying to show a heatmap over a static map by using the static map api and PHP.
I've been able to generate the static map but when trying to add the heatmap layer, I am not able to do so.
I've trying adding an inline geojson source and an external geojson file, both by using addsource and directly in the addlayer parameter of the url, but none of them worked.

May anybody please show an example of this or guide me somehow?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
To show and example, trying to replicate the earthquake example:

```php
$url  = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/static/-120,50/access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN';
$url .= "&addsource={'earthquakes',{'type':'geojson','data':'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson'}}";
$url .= "&addlayer={'id':'earthquakes-heat','type':'heatmap','source':'earthquakes','maxzoom':'9'}";
```

When I try this, console shows

> 'message   "Invalid layer passed to addlayer. Unable to parse JSON."'

I just want to create a map image, which I do with the first code line shown above, and pass some geo points to receive a heatmap image, but haven't been able to do so.

I have tried to use inline geojson, remote geojson, mix with mapbox studio (where I easily create a heatmap) and some variants, but I sincerely don't know what I am missing.

Comment: To the person who voted negative, I'm sorry not having managed to transmit my efforts. I've been trying to solve this for over a week before coming here :( Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with mapbox. But from the code sample and error message, you shared, I see a couple of issues.

1. Input **JSON is invalid**. JSON standard does not allow single quoted strings. See [RFC 7159 - 7.  Strings](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-7).

Layer source JSON format looks wrong. It feels like `earthquakes` should be a property rather than a value.

```json
{"earthquakes": {"type": "geojson", "data": "https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson"}}
```

Also I guess, `maxzoom` should be integer/numeric in layer JSON.

```json
{"id": "earthquakes-heat", "type": "heatmap", "source": "earthquakes", "maxzoom": 9}
```

All this modifications is just a guesses based on how JSON format allows it. Double check with documentation.

2. **Url data is not encoded**. Doesn't seem to be the case here. But to be on a safe side is better to encode data provided via url.

You could do so with help of [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```php
$url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/static/-120,50/access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN';
$url .= http_build_query([
    'addsource' => '{"earthquakes": {"type": "geojson", "data": "https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson"}}',
    'addlayer' => '{"id": "earthquakes-heat", "type": "heatmap", "source": "earthquakes", "maxzoom": 9}',
]);
```

Or using [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```php
$url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/static/-120,50/access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN';

$source = '{"earthquakes": {"type": "geojson", "data": "https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson"}}';
$url .= '&addsource=' . urlencode($source);

$layer = '{"id": "earthquakes-heat", "type": "heatmap", "source": "earthquakes", "maxzoom": 9}';
$url .= '&addlayer=' . urlencode($layer);
```

Hope this gonna help you, or at least giving you some hints how to solve the issue.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping!

I tried this:

JSON formatting was my fault, sorry. I think I am a little bit stressed with this issue :/

Once I built JSON correctly, response was _'The new layer's source reference key does not match any source keys in the requested style.'_

I guess the problem is I am missing how to send correctly requests concerning heatmaps.

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

So, @vstelmakh is right about the JSON formatting being incorrect in your original post. However, it's also worth mentioning the two additional issues with your current approach:

1. The Static Images API does not currently support an `addsource` query string parameter, so this information is being ignored at the time of your request.
2. GeoJSON sources are currently not supported for the `addlayer` query string parameter. In order to properly add a heatmap style layer, you will need to first upload your data as a mapbox tileset and then reference it within your addlayer param.

From the [API docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/static-images/#add-a-style-layer):

> To add a style layer from a source that is not already part of the style, you must specify source.url and source.type in the new style layer, like:
>
> ```
> "source": {
>   "type": "vector",
>   "url": "mapbox://{username}.{tileset}"
> }
> ```
>
> `source.url` must be a `mapbox://` tileset URL, and must be accessible to the access token used in the request. `source.type` must be either `raster` or `vector`.

---

*disclaimer: I currently work at Mapbox*